# How to select element based on another already-existing selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, document, designmode

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", 1);
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var rt, rt2;
            window.onload = function () {
                rt = $('#rt').contents().get(0);
                rt.designMode = 'On';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="rt" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

rt is currently selecting the whole iframe document. I want rt2 to select the body element inside the document element, which is what rt is selecting. I tried:

```
rt2 = jQuery(rt, "html");
rt2 = jQuery(rt2, "body");
```

But it didn't seem to work. How would it be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), the context to search within should be supplied as the second parameter, not the first, so try this instead:

```
rt2 = jQuery("html", rt);
```

The context can be:

> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Internally, the context is implemented using the `.find()` method. So the above example is just a short hand of:

```
rt2 = jQuery(rt).find("html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var myFrame = $('#rt').contents();
var myvar = myFrame.find('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
rt2body = iframeElement.find("body");
```

Further reading on .find: http://api.jquery.com/find/